# MySQL update value from the same table with count

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

What I want to do is to set every patient its unique patient code which starts with 1 and it's not based on row id. Id only specifies order. Something like this:

```
patient_id  patient_code
    2           1
    3           2
    4           3
```

This is my query:

```
UPDATE patients p1
SET p1.patient_code = (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) 
    FROM patients p2
    WHERE p2.patient_id <= p1.patient_id 
)
```

But it is throwing error:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'p1' for update in FROM clause
```

I found this thread: [Mysql error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause).
But I don't know how to apply approved answer this to work with subquery WHERE which is necessary for COUNT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    patients AS p
  JOIN
    ( SELECT 
          p1.patient_id
        , COUNT(*) AS cnt 
      FROM 
          patients AS p1
        JOIN 
          patients AS p2
            ON p2.patient_id <= p1.patient_id 
      GROUP BY 
          p1.patient_id
    ) AS g
    ON g.patient_id = p.patient_id
SET 
    p.patient_code = g.cnt ;
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks. My solution is faster, but has also some limitations

Comment: Could you explain why you use <= in the JOIN statement? why not just =?

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized this was in the original question... ignore my comment before...

Comment: Yes, it's a "triangular" self-join, used to provide numbers from 1 to N.

Answer (score 3):

I found working solution, but this is just workaround:

```
SET @code=0;
UPDATE patients SET patient_code = (SELECT @code:=@code+1 AS code)
```

Comment: You may want to add `ORDER BY patient_id` (MySQL allows ORDER BY in an UPDATE without joins).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
UPDATE patients p1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count,patient_id
    FROM patients
    group by patient_id  
)p2 
SET p1.patient_code=p2.count
WHERE p2.patient_id <= p1.patient_id
```

[**SQL_LIVE_DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e39d6)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Mari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14139078/5621032) I found a solution to my similar problem. But I wanted to add a bit of an explanation which for me at first wasn't too clear from his answer.

What I wanted to do would have been as simple as the following:

```
UPDATE my_comments AS c 
SET c.comment_responses = (
   SELECT COUNT(c1.*) FROM my_comments AS c1
   WHERE c.uid = c.parent_uid
);
```

Thanks to Mari I then found the solution on how to achieve this without running into the error `You can't specify target table 'p1' for update in FROM clause`:

```
UPDATE my_comments AS c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT c1.parent_uid, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM my_comments AS c1
        WHERE c1.parent_uid <> 0
        GROUP BY c1.parent_uid
) AS c2
SET c.comment_responses = c2.cnt
WHERE c2.parent_uid = c.uid;
```

My problems before getting to this solution were 2:

1. the `parent_uid` field doesn't always contain an id of a parent which is why I added the `WHERE` statement in the inner join
2. I didn't quite understand why I would need the `GROUP BY` until I executed the `SELECT` statement on it's own and the answer is: because `COUNT` groups the result and really counts everything. In order to prevent this behavior the `GROUP BY` is needed. In my case I didn't have to group it by `uid` though but the `parent_uid` to get the correct count. If I grouped it by `uid` the `COUNT` would always be 1 but the `parent_uid` existed multiple times in the result. I suggest you check the `SELECT` statement on it's own to check if it's the result you expect before you execute the full `UPDATE` statement.